# Why is Some(null) converted to None when mapping DataFrame to a case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In REPL, supplying a `Some(null)` argument to a case class constructor yields no surprise, the value is preserved and assigned to the field of the case class:

```
scala> case class CaseClassWithOptionField(opt:Option[String])
defined class CaseClassWithOptionField

scala> CaseClassWithOptionField(Some(null))
res0: CaseClassWithOptionField = CaseClassWithOptionField(Some(null))
```

However, when I map a DataFrame to a case class that has a field of type `Option[T]`, `Some(null)` becomes a `None`: (I ran this in a Jupyter notebook)

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

val someDF = Seq(
  (8, Some(null.asInstanceOf[String])),
  (64, Some(null.asInstanceOf[String])),
  (-27, Some(null.asInstanceOf[String]))
).toDF("id", "opt")

case class CCWithOpt(id: Int, opt: Option[String])

someDF.as[CCWithOpt] take 1 // gives [CCWithOpt(8,None)]
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark interprets `Option[T]`-typed column in a DataFrame as a `nullable` column of type `T`.  For example:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, Some("a"), Some(1)),
  (2, Some(null), Some(2)),
  (3, Some("c"), Some(3)),
  (4, None, None)
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

df.show
// +---+----+----+
// | c1|  c2|  c3|
// +---+----+----+
// |  1|   a|   1|
// |  2|null|   2|
// |  3|   c|   3|
// |  4|null|null|
// +---+----+----+

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c3: integer (nullable = true)
```

Note that in column `c2`, `Some(null)` is treated the same as `None`.

For your `someDF` DataFrame, Spark infers the `opt` column as `nullable` column of `String` and treats `Some(null.asInstanceOf[String])` as `null`.  When it's converted to `Dataset[CCWithOpt]`, the `null` gets restored to `None`.

Comment: So when a row in the DataFrame is being converted to an instance of `CCWithOpt `, a `null` is supplied as the second argument to the `CCWithOpt` constructor? That would require some magic to happen to convert `null` to `None`. I tried to look at the source code of the `as[U : Encoder]: Dataset[U]` function and didn't see any specific Encoder for Option[T] type. I would like to know more details about what exactly is happening.

Comment: @Juraj, the `null/None check` for non-`flat` encoders in org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.[ExpressionEncoder](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder.scala) hints at how `null` and `None` are cross-checked.

Comment: Ran your answer in v 2.4 and got into errors.  java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.NullPointerException. A pointer would be appreciated. Ran in Databricks.

Comment: @thebluephantom, unfortunately I don't have the latest Spark to test it out.  The dataset as is works fine on Spark 2.2 / Jdk 8.  If Spark 2.4 is going to treat `Option`-typed data differently from earlier releases, I'm afraid lots of apps might break.  Anyway, I would first try replace `Some(null)` with `None`, and if that still doesn't work, make column `c1` also type `Option`.

Comment: 2.4 Databricks. Thx.

Comment: I ended up having to do something like this, but I am not the expert in Scala yet: val df = Seq(
//  (1, "a", 1), // get Any error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
  (1, "a",  1.asInstanceOf[Integer]),
  (2,  null, null),
  (3,  "c",  3.asInstanceOf[Integer])
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

Comment: Under 2.2 with paste ran the above fine. With 2.4 Databricks! the Some(null) will not work, all None are fine. Not sure what that would mean

Comment: @thebluephantom, if the later versions only "dislike" `Some(null)`, the sample dataset in this case would fail, but the impact might not be too bad – since in practice (say, when generating a new column using a UDF), one can easily avoid `Some(null)` and use `None` instead to represent `null`s.

Comment: No, I realize that. But it seems odd that support seems to have dropped... surely over there in San Fran?

Comment: Comments made by JL: Regardless of the root cause, I'd report it as an issue in JIRA @ issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK as NPE in such a low-level code is certainly a bug and should not be seen by an end user. – Jacek Laskowsk.  I think I should leave the honours to you Sir.

Comment: Can you confirm you will do else I will ask JL to do that.

Comment: @thebluephantom, thanks for keeping me in the loop.  Please go ahead and report it as you see fit.  Technically though, if `None` represents `null`, `Some(null)`shouldn't have been used in the first place – thus rejecting `Some(null)` doesn't really bother me that much, other than that it would break backward compatibility in some corner use case.

Comment: @LeoC  Not sure I should or not. JL felt but  I felt you may be the better person to report.

Comment: I'm not going to report it at this point since 1) I haven't experienced it myself (not on the latest Spark), and 2) it might not be all that bad to discourage the use of `Some(null)` for the reason mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Created JIRA issue - fyi.